# string value was not compared correctly

Tags: mariadb-10.4

database charset : latin1
database collation: latin1_swedish_ci

table charset : latin1
table collation: latin1_swedish_ci

connection charset : UTF8
connection collation :  utf8_general_ci

query was working fine for years. But on a day I had a problem, query was not working.
While checking on the query, I found string value was not compared correctly, only for that column in this query only.
In some database  query was working fine.
Now temporarily I have fixed by using BINARY before the column name and the query is working fine.
I want to know what is the reason for this situation and how to solve permanantly  .

I have fixed by using BINARY before the column name and the query is working fine. I want a permanent solution